# bash or operator with exit status

Tags: bash, if-statement

Is it possible to have two expressions in a bash if statement, using an 'or' operator, in which one of the expressions tests the exit status of grep?

For example, I want a script to process all directories in my PATH *except* for '.' and /home/$LOGNAME/bin. I can do it fine with two if statements, but I'd like to combine the two tests into a single statement joined by 'or'.

This is the working version (two separate if statements):

```
IFS=:

for VAR in $PATH ; do
  if echo $VAR | grep /home/$LOGNAME/bin > /dev/null
  then
    echo SKIPPING YOUR OWN bin DIRECTORY \($VAR\)
  elif [ "$VAR" = "." ]
  then
    echo SKIPPING CURRENT WORKING DIRECTORY \($VAR\)
  else
    echo processing $VAR
  fi
done
```

.. which produces the following output:

```
SKIPPING CURRENT WORKING DIRECTORY (.)
SKIPPING YOUR OWN bin DIRECTORY (/home/bobo/bin)
processing /home/qa/utils
processing /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin
processing /usr/local/bin
processing /bin
processing /usr/bin
processing /usr/local/sbin
processing /usr/sbin
processing /sbin
```

Just a few of many failed attempts:

```
if [ ( echo $VAR | grep /home/$LOGNAME > /dev/null )] -o [ "$VAR" = "." ]
if [[ ( echo $VAR | grep /home/$LOGNAME > /dev/null ) ]] -o [[ "$VAR" = "." ]]
if ( echo $VAR | grep /home/$LOGNAME > /dev/null ) -o "$VAR" = "."
if ( echo $VAR | grep /home/$LOGNAME > /dev/null ) || "$VAR" = "."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper form for your if elif fi block can be like this. You also don't need to use an external binary command like `grep`.

```
IFS=:

for VAR in $PATH; do
  if [[ $VAR == . ]]; then
    echo "SKIPPING CURRENT WORKING DIRECTORY \($VAR\)"
  elif [[ "$VAR" == "/home/$LOGNAME/bin"* ]]; then
    echo "SKIPPING YOUR OWN bin DIRECTORY \($VAR\)"
  else
    echo "processing $VAR"
  fi
done
```

If you want to do it with one line you could have:

```
IFS=:

for VAR in $PATH; do
  if [[ $VAR != . && "$VAR" != "/home/$LOGNAME/bin"* ]]; then
    echo "processing $VAR"
  else
    echo "SKIPPING CURRENT WORKING DIRECTORY OR YOUR OWN bin DIRECTORY \($VAR\)"
  fi
done
```

Or

```
IFS=:

for VAR in $PATH; do
  if [[ $VAR == . || "$VAR" == "/home/$LOGNAME/bin"* ]]; then
    echo "SKIPPING CURRENT WORKING DIRECTORY OR YOUR OWN bin DIRECTORY \($VAR\)"
  else
    echo "processing $VAR"    
  fi
done
```

The `else` block is optional.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but totally unnecessary. Just let `if` evaluate the exit status of `grep` directly:

```
if echo "$var" | grep -q "$HOME/bin" || test "$var" = . ; then
  ...
fi
```

or

```
if echo "$var" | grep -q "^$HOME"'/bin$\|^\.$'; then ...
```

Note that the semantics of these are slightly different, since the second requires that $HOME/bin be the entire line, but that is probably what you want.  (The anchors should be in the first example, if that is the case.)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. Using your `if` construct, it could look something like this (although there are a couple other equally valid ways to do it):

```
if [[ "${VAR}" == "." ]] || grep -q /home/${LOGNAME}/bin <<< "${VAR}"
```

You might also consider something like this, which I think makes it a bit clearer what you're doing, and might even be less typing (it also dispenses with calling an external program, so will be slightly more efficient):

```
case "${VAR}" in
  .|*/home/${LOGNAME}/bin*) .... ;;
  *) .... ;;
esac
```